# Getting text with UITextField Popup Alertview with Swift 3 fatal error

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift3

I have popup alert and getting text with UITextField codes but when i want to get text string gives me nil error. my codes here. Im using Xcode latest and Swift 3.

```
   var tField: UITextField!


   @IBAction func addcommentButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {


    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Write Comment", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert.addTextField { (configurationTextField) in

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler:self.handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
    print("Done !!")


       let textField = self.tField.text // HERE GIVES ERROR nil = tField


        if  textField != nil {
              print("Item : \(textField))")
        }



    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
    print("completion block")
    })

    }

    }
```

Error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Error line

> let textField = self.tField.text // HERE GIVES ERROR nil = tField

Thank you !

Comment: Do you ever assign something to `self.tField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added your `alert` `action` inside the `addTextField` closure also you need to use first textField from array of textFields of the `alertController` so you need to change your code like this

```
@IBAction func addcommentButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Write Comment", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler:self.handleCancel))
   alert.addTextField { (configurationTextField) in
       //configure here your textfield
       configurationTextField.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
   }
   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Send", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
       print("Done !!")
       if let textField = alert.textFields?.first {
           print("Item : \(textField.text))")
       }
   }))
   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
       print("completion block")
   })    
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate Happy Coding :)

Comment: 0
down vote
Shouldn't it just be: let textField = alert.textFields?.first as downcasts from UITextField? only unwraps optionals?

Comment: @TaichiKato Edited the answer and also unwrapped the optional.

Comment: Thanks man, the code works well, I just wanted to let you know so people viewing this won't face the same issue.